# Google Retail API (Recommendations AI): how can i retrieve/export user events?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-recommendation

I would like to export my all user events. Is there a way to retrieve all user events data with API ? I can retrieve products: **[list_products](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/retail/latest/google.cloud.retail_v2.services.product_service.ProductServiceClient?authuser=1#google_cloud_retail_v2_services_product_service_ProductServiceClient_list_products)**:

```
from google.cloud import retail_v2

def sample_list_products():
    # Create a client
    client = retail_v2.ProductServiceClient()

    # Initialize request argument(s)
    request = retail_v2.ListProductsRequest(
        parent="parent_value",
    )

    # Make the request
    page_result = client.list_products(request=request)

    # Handle the response
    for response in page_result:
        print(response)
```

Comment: https://www.googlecloudcommunity.com/gc/AI-ML/Retail-API-how-can-i-retrieve-export-user-events/td-p/610700?nobounce

Comment: The solution is in the link above.